# Set zoom level of google map based on different lat and long

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have different sites drawn on google map(basically polygon/circle). A site can be anywhere in the world on google map. I have center lat and long of sites(polygon/circle) in an array and I want to set the zoom level of the map so that all the sites can be seen in one view.

For e.g. if there is only one site to display in map, zoom level should be more.

Please help me in this. I am looking for javascript code.

Comment: got through the latlngbounds documentation in google maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try this hint**

```
var latlngBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
```

*array of latlng object;*

```
for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
   latlngBounds.extend(array[i]);
}

map.fitBounds(latlngBounds);
```

Comment: Thanks @Akshay padwal your answer helped me to an extend